# Calculate the sum of all durations of all objects in array using moment js

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I get array of object, they all have field duration, that is a string;
Example of object :

```
  {
    id: 14070
    project: {id: 87, name: "Test project for time tracking"}
    issue: {id: 10940}
    user: {id: 107, name: "Alexander Kirillov"}
    activity: {id: 9, name: "Development"}
    hours: 0.01
    comments: "RARA"
    spent_on: "2020-03-23"
    created_on: "2020-03-23T14:58:18Z"
    updated_on: "2020-03-23T14:58:26Z"
    custom_fields: (2) [{…}, {…}]
    start: "Mon, 23rd Mar"
    duration: "00:01" // HH:mm
    __proto__: Object
    }
```

the array name is timeEntries = [{},{},...];
How I can calculate the sum of all durations of all objects in timeEntries using moment js? Thanks in forward!!!

Comment: Do you mean "the sum of all durations of all objects in `timeEntries`"?

Comment: @Titulum Yes, sry for bad description

Comment: Is the duration format `HH:mm` or `mm:ss`?

Comment: @Titulum HH:mm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that like so:

```js
const timeEntries = [{
    duration: "00:01"
  },
  {
    duration: "01:00"
  },
  {
    duration: "12:30"
  }
];

const totalDurations = timeEntries.slice(1)
  .reduce((prev, cur) => {
      return prev.add(cur.duration);
    },
    moment.duration(timeEntries[0].duration));

console.log(`Total duration is: ${moment.utc(totalDurations.asMilliseconds()).format("HH:mm")}`);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Even better! Forgot that we could add the dependency here also

Comment: why we need to make slice(1)?

Comment: We want to remove the first item from the array before using `reduce`, otherwise the first item will be processed twice!

Answer (score 1):

I've found solution:

```
const totalDurations = durations.split(1).reduce(
  (prev, cur) => moment.duration(cur).add(prev),
  moment.duration(durations[0])
).format("HH:mm");
```